# How do you copy a MS SQL 2000 database programmatically using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dts

I need to copy several tables from one DB to another in SQL Server 2000, using C# (VS 2005).  The call needs to be parameterized - I need to be able to pass in the name of the database to which I am going to be copying these tables.

I could use DTS with parameters, but I can't find any sample code that does this from C#.

Alternatively, I could just use

```
drop table TableName
select * into TableName from SourceDB..TableName
```

and then reconstruct the indexes etc - but that is **really** kludgy.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you can't find c# sample code for DTS, do you mean sample code to execute a DTS package, or sample code to copy tables within a DTS package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 7.0 and 2000, we have SQLDMO for this. For SQL Server 2005 there is SMO. This allows you do to pretty much everything related to administering the database, scripting objects, enumerating databases, and much more. This is better, IMO, than trying a "roll your own" approach.

SQL 2000:
[Developing SQL-DMO Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa274758(SQL.80).aspx)

[Transfer Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276080(SQL.80).aspx)

SQL 2005:
Here is the SMO main page:
[Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169(SQL.90).aspx)

Here is the Transfer functionality:
[Transferring Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162563(SQL.90).aspx)

[How to: Transfer Schema and Data from One Database to Another in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162138(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the destination table is being dropped every time then why not do SELECT INTO? Doesn't seem like a kludge at all.

If it works just fine and ticks all the requirements boxes why create a days worth of work growing code to do exactly the same thing?

Let SQL do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: It can get tricky with FK dependencies and stuff like that.  I'm not saying it wouldn't work, it just strikes me as being very inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the scripts (copy db)  found here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CreateDatabaseScript.aspx

Into an application. Just replace the destination. To actually move the entite database, FOLLOW

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546

But remember, the database has to be taken offline first.

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice, but the CodeProject script is for SQL 2005; I only have SQL 2000.

Comment: Look at the Books Online for SQL Server 2000, type "Copy Database" and you'll get information there.