# Generate Multiple and Filtered Drop + Create Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, system-stored-procedures

I have this script:

```
select name,create_date,modify_date from sys.procedures order by modify_date desc
```

I can see what procedures were modified lately.
I will add a "where modify_date >=  "
And I'd like to use some system stored procedure, that will generate me :
drop + create scripts for the (let's say 5 matching) stored procedures

Can i do this somehow?

thanks

---

ok. i have the final version:

http://swooshcode.blogspot.com/2008/10/generate-stored-procedures-scripts-for.html

you guys helped a lot

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ain't pretty, but it works. Run the output from it manually or execute it with sp_executesql.

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id), 'drop procedure [' + name + ']'
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE modify_date >= @date
```

You will have to worry about lost rights as well.

Answer (score 1):

No cursor necessary (modify as desired for schemas, etc):

```
DECLARE @dt AS datetime
SET @dt = '10/1/2008'

DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql, '')
    + '-- ' + o.name + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + o.name + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + m.definition + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.sql_modules AS m
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
    ON m.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE p.modify_date >= @dt

PRINT @sql -- or EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cursor to iterate through each record:

```
DECLARE @spName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.procedures ORDER BY modify_date DESC
OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @spName
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    -- Process each stored procedure with a dynamic query
    PRINT @spName
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @spName
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: this was my idea also, but i thought there might be a system stored proc, that is doing the:

-- Process each stored procedure with a dynamic query

part ... you know what i mean?
(there has to be something like sp_generatesp 'sp_myproc' ... i guess)

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i did some digging, and seems like

```
sp_helptext 'my_stored_procedure'
```

is what i need, (plus the part that i already knew when i asked the question explained more by jdecuyper)

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in a more suitable language than SQL. Despite its numerous extensions such as T-SQL, PL/SQL, and PL/pgSQL, SQL is not the best thing for this task.

Here is a link to a similar question, and my answer, which was to use SQL-DMO or SMO, depending on whether you have SQL 2000 or 2005.

[How to copy a database with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174515/how-do-you-copy-a-ms-sql-2000-database-programmatically-using-c#175062)